# I'm using the IN operator yet I still get the error: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve this challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sql-projects/problem.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT start_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE
    (SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
    ORDER BY start_date ASC) AS start_date,
    
    (SELECT end_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE
    (SELECT DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) NOT IN (SELECT end_date FROM projects)
    ORDER BY end_date ASC) AS end_date
    
FROM projects p
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) ASC, start_date ASC
```

Nonetheless,I got the following error: 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' Despite using the NOT IN operator.

However, when I tried executing only this part of the code:

```
SELECT start_date
FROM projects p
WHERE (SELECT (DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
ORDER BY start_date ASC
```

It worked fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select project rows. Per project row you select a start date. The query for the this start date looks like this:

```
(SELECT start_date ... ORDER BY start_date ASC)
```

Do you really think it is one start_date you are selecting here? Why then the `ORDER BY` clause? This subquery returns multiple rows and this is why you are getting the error.

This query does not selects one start date, but all start dates for which not exists the previous date in the table. It doesn't even relate to the project row in the main query.

It seems you want to find all start dates that have no predecessor and all end dates that have no follower. These are two data sets you can select from. So the subqueries don't belong in the `SELECT` clause where you say which columns to select, but in the `FROM` clause where you say from which data sets to select.

You would then have to join the two sets. The join criteria would be the rows' positions in the ordered data sets (first start date belongs to first end date, second start date belongs to second end date, ...). For this you need a way to number these data rows.

Such a task is easy to solve with `ROW_NUMBER`. This is only featured since MySQL 8.

```
SELECT s.start_date, e.end_date
FROM
(
  SELECT start_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_date) AS rn
  FROM projects 
  WHERE start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
) s
JOIN
(
  SELECT end_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY end_date) AS rn
  FROM projects 
  WHERE start_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY NOT IN (SELECT end_date FROM projects)
) e USING (rn)
ORDER BY s.start_date;
```

This kind of problem is called gaps & islands. There are other ways to solve this, but I think that above query plainly builds up on yours and is thus easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The two subquery for start _date and end_date could return a different numbers of rows  adn any way the db engine not allow so called  "parallel query"

in this case you should gets all the date involved  and the  left join for the subquery

```
select t1.start_date, t2.end_date

from (
    SELECT start_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)  NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
    UNION 
    SELECT end_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE SELECT DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY) NOT IN (SELECT end_date FROM projects)

    ) t 
left join (

    SELECT start_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)  NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
    ) t1 on t.start_date = t1.start_date
left join (

    SELECT end_date
    FROM projects 
    WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL -1 DAY)  NOT IN (SELECT start_date FROM projects)
    ) t2 on t.start_date = t2.start_date
order by t1.syaty_date
```

Comment: I checked the result of the two subqueries independently and they returned the same number of rows. The characteristics of the table, and the way in which the two subqueries are written, guarantee that they will return the same number of rows.

Comment: This is not what the db engine think  .. is not  pssible use "parallel query "

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer that may explain better what you are doing.

You can:

```
select 
  start_date,
  end_date,
  start_date - interval 1 day as prev_day,
  1 as one
from projects;
```

The select clause contains what you want to select from a projects row. For the first row you will get its start date, end date, its start date minus one day, and a 1 we call "one" here. For the second row you will get its start date (which is probably another start date than the one of the first row), its end date, its start date minus one day, and again a 1 we call "one".

You can

```
select 
  (select start_date) as start_date,
  (select end_date) as end_date,
  (select start_date - interval 1 day) as prev_day,
  (select 1) as one
from projects;
```

which doesn't change anything and only obfuscates things. (This is what you do here: `(SELECT DATE_ADD(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))`.

You cannot

```
select 
  (select start_date from projects) as start_date,
  (select end_date from projects) as end_date,
  (select start_date - interval 1 day from projects) as prev_day,
  (select 1 from projects) as one
from projects;
```

because here you are not selecting one value for the first project row's start date, but all start dates from the table. Same for its end date etc. of course, same for the second row etc. This is what you are doing here:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT start_date FROM projects ...) AS start_date,
  (SELECT end_date FROM projects ...) AS end_date
FROM projects p
```

and this is why you are getting the error "Subquery returns more than 1 row".